# Have a salesforce flow, and once the record gets created in the flow, the flow to redirect to detail page of new record

Tags: redirect, salesforce, salesforce-flow

Have a salesforce flow, and once the new case record gets created in the flow, after the flow finished it has to redirect to detail page of new case record created

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this as long as you are using a screen flow. You can pass through the recordId.

You would just need to create a variable in the flow, like "recordID", it will pass the record ID of the case you just made to that variable(as long as it allows input of course). Snag the current user id by creating a formula that way you can get it directly from the flow.

I didn't write this article, but I think it might also give you some clarity. https://englhardconsulting.com/dynamically-redirect-your-flow/